# ArcGIS Field Calculator returning 0 values when decimals are expected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I realize I posed this question, and got answers, several days ago (see [Field calculator error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57210/field-calculator-error)) , but none seem to really be working, and so am posing again.

Below are two screenshots that show the fields with field properties, and another showing the field calculator and the equation with the "answer" field populated by 0s. I apologize for them not being next to each other or in line with the appropriate text, but the web formatting keeps overlaying them.

Here is an overview of the problem: I am trying to do a in field calculator, where I'm trying to populate a new field with the values from a fairly simple equation of one field divided by another (Cnt1 by Pop1 in this case).

Both fields that I am dividing are double, and the value, while small is not infinitesimal, approx 0.01765.

I have tried creating various types of new fields: double, long, float, and played around with the scale/precision/properties, but everytime it returns "0" values. I know the values will be very small, i.e .04 but it doesn't seem to be a decimal display problem as I tried running it with Pop1/.4 and it correctly returned a decimal.

I've tested dividing the Cnt1 by .5 and that gives an appropriate decimal value, so it's not the new field format; **the one thing that seems really strange is when I add (in field calculator python version): !Cnt1!+!Pop1! (which is 38+218699) I get 2.187**, however, I suppose this could be related to the field being classified as float with precision=4, scale=3?

[image]

I've also tried the suggestions of @blord-castillo of doing:

```
1.0* (Cnt1/Pop1)
```

and also 
    1.0* (int(Cnt1/Pop1))
But neither works, I'm at my wits end on this one, and would greatly appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: In 10.0 the default interpreter is VBscript.  Any chance you haven't selected Python?

Comment: Hi Roy, that's a good thought; unfortunately, I double checked and Python is selected.

Comment: Do you have spaces around each mathematical operator? (the plus signs and slash) Field Calculator can be quite finicky about that.

Comment: At least for a double, leave it at 0,0 for the precision and scale. I would check the number format setting for the field.

Comment: It's hard to follow what error from what input you are up to in your two questions.  Are you able to re-phrase this one to something along the lines of "when I ran this Python code in the Python window, I received this error", please?

Comment: @PolyGeo, I've clarified by indicating the problem I'm describing at present is in field calculator.

Comment: Can you add to your post the properties of each input and output field (type) ?

Comment: I got confused by comment in other question "I was testing this out in Field Calculator, but the real objective is for it to run in a stand alone python script." I was hoping you might be able to revise both Questions to facilitate a cleaner Q & A style response.

Comment: @A.R, I've added the input/output values.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I think trying to clarify this will just confuse some by adding extra text and complexity; the python stand alone part is essentially irrelevant because the problem exists as a straight calculation problem in Field Calculator. If there is still confusion please indicate so.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your attribute table so we have an idea of what you're working with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Field calculator error](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57210/field-calculator-error)

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57400.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran a test at **ArcGIS 10.0 SP5**.

You can see my results below.

[image]

To achieve this in a **file geodatabase** polygon feature class, I had field cnt1 as Short Integer, pop1 as Long Integer, and Stnd3 as Double.

In the **Field Calculator** I used:

Stnd3=

```
float(!cnt1!) / float(!pop1!)
```

I then used the context menu of the Stnd3 field to access the **Numeric...** button on its **Properties** to set the **Number of decimal places** to 9.

Is this the result you are after?

Comment: wow! This is perfect, it is exactly what I'm looking for. So the question for me to learn from this is why? Can you help me understand why the fields each need to be formatted differently in order to get the calculation to work?

Comment: It's probably confusion over different syntaxes needed for different parsers (VB,Python) and data type (File & Personal Geodatabases, shapefiles) combinations.  I stick with Python and File Geodatabases wherever possible.  The other thing is to just use the Numeric... button to format how many decimal places and allow the File Geodatabase to just store Float/Double (whichever you need).  I prefer to use the Python float function to convert integers rather than just multiplying by 1.0 (but I think that should have worked too).

Comment: update is apparently this is a problem with my machine or SP or something as this still isn't working. Had someone try it on another machine and same code worked. Hmmm

Comment: question that year sago solved many problems with arcgis calculations: what is your windows format (region and Language in Control Panel) ?? did anyone by mistake changed the Numbers format (open additional settings and 2-check the Numbers formats). I hope it helps

Comment: wow! "poly-geo" has halted premature grey hairs spreading across my head. thank you! poly-geo should start his/her own website and charge subscribers a fee. well done.

Answer (score 4):

You need to force float calculation. Right now you are doing integer math (I assume all of your source fields are `short` or `long`, hence the results you are getting), so if your result value is less than 1, it is flooring the value down to the next integer, which is zero. The *type* of the *destination* field does not matter.

This is very easy to fix. Do your calculation like this:

```
1.0 * (Cnt1+Cnt2+Cnt3)/ (Pop1+Pop2+Pop3)
```

The 1.0 out front (not 1, but 1.0) forces a float calculation without altering your end result. (Same thing happened when you did `Pop1/.4` The 0.4 was a float value, so that forced float calculation.) If any of your source fields were `float`, you would also have ended up with `float` math instead of integer math (at least at 10.1 where I tested this).

Comment: You noted below that your source fields are doubles. So the consideration of source field type might be a 10.1 thing; and the fields are being coerced to integers since they contain whole numbers.

Comment: Many thanks blord-castillo, this worked perfectly. Problem solved.

Comment: Actually, problem temporarily solved, I was testing this out in Field Calculator, but the real objective is for it to run in a stand alone python script. However, when I run it in the script I get the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gislab2\Python\take_home\part1\prelim_if2.py", line 45, in <module>
    Field_name= 1.0*(int("Cnt1"+"Cnt2"+"Cnt3")/("Pop1"+"Pop2"+"Pop3"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Cnt1Cnt2Cnt3'                                              I only put the (int( part in as I  got an error  it couldn't multiply 1.0 by string

Comment: Yes, what you are doing there is concatenating the string, not doing addition. What function are you feeding field name into?

Comment: Good point blord, I'm not feeding the fieldname into any function, so very basic question then, the process is i need to define a function which includes the equation: 1.0*(int("Cnt1"+"Cnt2"+"Cnt3")/("Pop1"+"Pop2"+"Pop3"))         I'm a little confused, though, re: your first point about the concatenation, as this code in the field calculator will function as addition, does it act differently in a script?

Comment: Yes, in a script, saying "Cnt1"+"Cnt2"+"Cnt3" causes string concatenation to execute before int() is executed. So, it concatenates the string, forming "Cnt1Cnt2Cnt3" and then tries to execute int("Cnt1Cnt2Cnt3"). It will not reference your field values at any point. Since "Cnt1Cnt2Cnt3" is not an integer, it cannot coerce it into an integer and int() fails. I think it would be okay to start a second question for how to do this in a script. Then you could provide your script code to look at.

Comment: @David Meek - What works in the field calculator won't usually work in a stand-alone script.  If you are going stand alone, try using a cursor to grab your values, do the calculation, and update your field. [check arcgis resources](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)

Answer (score 2):

The general format for python based field calculations is as follows:

> (!Cnt1! + !Cnt2! + !Cnt3!) / (!Pop1! + !Pop2! + !Pop3!)

where fields are specified as `!fields!` in the equation.

Also, try specifying [Float](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000p000000) for the new field you create.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your response; I have it in the format you specified (!Cnt1! + !Cnt1! + !Cnt1!) / (!Pop1! + !Pop2! + !Pop3!); also I've tried specifying the field as Float, but still no dice.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your response; I have it in the format you specified (!Cnt1! + !Cnt1! + !Cnt1!) / (!Pop1! + !Pop2! + !Pop3!); also I've tried specifying the field as Float, but still no dice

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm way late on this one and so the point might be moot, but this happened to me today (02/01/17) using a dbf table.  As I was looking for an answer in this forum, I decided to exit my project and open the dbf table in a new blank project.  I added the table, created the new field as double, and proceeded to do the calculation among three variables - all double.  Viola!  No zeroes!  Strange how ArcMap acts sometimes.  I've found when stuff like this happens using the Field Calculator, the best thing to do is exit the project, re-open it, and run the Calculator again; but this is the first time I've had to start a brand new project to overcome the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I see you said that you've played around with field properties, but you didn't say which fields you did that for. The ones I'd check for sure are the population fields because 1) they are used in the denominator and 2) population figures are usually integers. Make sure you either make your population fields float/double or cast the values as floats when you make the calculations.

Comment: Jason, good thoughts: to clarify, I've only tinkered with the properties of the new fields I've tried creating, but have checked the properties of the POP and CNT fields. They've shown DOUBLE under properties, but is it possible the data are still string in those fields? If so, would it be advisable to create a new set of POP and CNT fields where I take the original values and force double them? Thanks again, david